# ASP.NET MVC4 date format in dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code in my Model;

```
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]    
 public DateTime? StartProject { get; set; }
```

in my View;

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartProject)
```

and the jquery

```
$("#StartProject").datepicker(
{ dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" }     
);
```

It outputs something like 01/01/2015 but i would to show in this format 01-01-2014.

How can i do this?Thanks.

Comment: Use $("#StartProject").datepicker( { dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy" } ).val (); This will give date in 01-01-2014 format.

Answer (score 1):

Can't duplicate your issue.  Using the code below returns date in `MM-dd-yyyy (01-05-2015)` format.

ViewModel:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0: MM-dd-yyyy h:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime StartProject { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartProject, new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartProject, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $('#StartProject').datepicker({
            format: "mm-dd-yyyy"
    });
</script>
}
```

Comment: it was so in my jquery. look at my question. I want that user can enter in this format "dd-mm-yyyy". but it can't in this current code!

Answer (score 0):

do it this way

```
     <script>
    $(function () {

        $("#StartProject").datepicker();
        $("#StartProject").datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work. If i use u code than i don't have the datepicker of the Jquery.

Comment: @Tekinnn : use it in script tag like that of answer

Comment: it was so in my jquery. look at my question. I want that user can enter in this format "dd-mm-yyyy". but it can't in this current code!

Comment: You can add a new project it works but if i want to edit than i have this error.  

    The field must be a date

Answer (score 0):

in model

```
public Nullable<System.DateTime> Period_From { get; set; }
```

view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartProject,"{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { type = "text", Class = "form-control dp1", placeholder = "DD/MM/YYYY", style="font-size:12px;" })
```

js

```
 $('.dp1').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
```